# unable to connect to azure gen2 storage account in South Central US region from azure databrick in EAST US

Tags: azure, networking, azure-databricks, azure-storage-account, vnet

We are facing an access issue to connect azure storage account. Firewall is enabled in the storage account to provide access to only specific IPs. Storage account is hosted in Azure South Central US.

We are trying to access data from azure databricks which is hosted in EAST US region.

Now issue is if databricks is also hosted in South central then we can easily whitelist databricks vnet and access storage. But in our case we can't do since vnet is only accessible within the region. We also don't have public IPs for databricks cluster.

We can't all traffic from all the networks.

Can someone suggest how can we access storage account from databricks in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual network in the region in which storage account (**vnet1**) is hosted

Then, you can do the **VNET peering** between **vnet1** and data bricks VNET

Now, you can add **vnet1** in the selected networks of the Azure Storage Account.

You would be able to connect to the Storage Account from the Data bricks

Comment: already tried not working

Comment: You can create private endpoint for storage account and host it in virtual network in the region in which storage account is hosted